# How in jQuery pass parameters into function after function fadeOut

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Hi how i can pass variable into this function

```
var _index = $("#sideNewsContent_menu li").index($(this)) + 1;

$("#sideNewsContent_body").fadeOut(300, function (index) {

     //HERE i want to use variable _index
});
```

Comment: It's already available to you.

Comment: Why cant you use it? It look 100% correct? Are you sure "$("#sideNewsContent_menu li").index($(this)) + 1" is returning a value

Comment: You just did! (Well, you didn't "pass" it, but it's available.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the fact the "_index" can be used in the closure that you are defining :

```
var _index = $("#sideNewsContent_menu li").index($(this)) + 1;
$("#sideNewsContent_body").fadeOut(300, function () {
 alert(_index);
});
```

In javascript, when you define an anonymous function (a closure), you can use all the variables that exist in the current context (except "this" which is a special keyword).

Answer (score 1):

It's already in the scope. Just be sure not to put `var _index` anywhere in the function, or it'll create a local variable called `_index`, which will take precedence over the `_index` variable in the closure.

```
var _index = $("#sideNewsContent_menu li").index($(this)) + 1;

$("#sideNewsContent_body").fadeOut(300, function (index) {

     _index++;

     alert(_index);
});
```

Don't do this:

```
$("#sideNewsContent_body").fadeOut(300, function (index) {

     var _index = _index++;

     alert(_index);
});
```